# count the number of distinct variables in a group

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame such as this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c('123','124','125','126'),
  Group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
  V1 = c(1,2,1,0),
  V2 = c(0,0,1,0),
  V3 = c(1,1,0,3))
```

which returns:

```
    ID Group V1 V2 V3
1 123     A  1  0  1
2 124     A  2  0  1
3 125     B  1  1  0
4 126     B  0  0  3
```

and I would like to return a table that indicates if a variable is represented in the group or not:

```
Group V1 V2 V3
A     1  0  1
B     1  1  1
```

In order to count the number of distinct variables in each group.

Comment: You can use `count` or `n_distinct`.  Question is not clear

Comment: `length(unique(mtcarts$cyl))`

Comment: imo it is pretty clear; i will reopen if OP proves otherwise

Comment: edited for clarification

Comment: You're just trying to see if some member of the group doesn't equal 0 on the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `base R`

```
aggregate(.~Group, df[-1], function(x) as.integer(sum(x)>0))
#  Group V1 V2 V3
#1     A  1  0  1
#2     B  1  1  1
```

---

Or using `rowsum` from `base R`

```
+(rowsum(df[-(1:2)], df$Group)>0)
#   V1 V2 V3
#A  1  0  1
#B  1  1  1
```

---

Or with `by` from `base R`

```
+(do.call(rbind, by(df[3:5], df['Group'], FUN = colSums))>0)
#   V1 V2 V3
#A  1  0  1
#B  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
unique(group_by(mtcars,cyl)$cyl).  

Output:[1] 6 4 8
```